# Gherkin plug in - Natural Installation Issue

Tags: eclipse-plugin, gherkin

While installing Natural plug in for Gherkin through Eclipse market place getting below error

[image: Installation error]

Answer (score 1):

This is because, repository location is moved to .io site from .com site. PSB for steps.

1. Navigate to Help - Install New Software.
2. Enter below URL - https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural
3. Select Natural
   [[image: Install Procedure 1][1]]

follow the prompts and install plugin. Restart eclipse.